# I am building a profile form for user which can accept gender in from of check box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<div class="field">    
     <%= f.label :gender %></br>
     <%= f.text_field :gender %>
</div>
```

I am using the above code to take input for gender of user.
But I want user to provide it in form of checkbox, 'm' for Male, 'f' for Female. 
How can I modify the code to accept gender in form of check box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A check box will send an explicit value through in params if it is checked.  It won't send anything if it's not checked.  This value is what your code will use.

A check box isn't the best input type to use here as you have two mutually exclusive options.  It's better to use radio buttons.  eg

```
<div class="field">    
   <%= f.label :gender %></br>
   <span class="option">Male<span><%= f.radio_button :gender, "m" %></br>
   <span class="option">Female<span><%= f.radio_button :gender, "f" %></br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using radio buttons instead for choices of this type, like so:

```
<div class="field"> 
    <%= radio_button_tag(:gender, "female") %>
    <%= label_tag(:gender_person, "I am a female") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:gender, "male") %>
    <%= label_tag(:gender_person, "I am a male") %>
</div>
```

Check boxes are poorly suited to present non-boolean options to users.

You could for example, put the checkmark in there and ask your users to check it if they are male for instance, or to leave it empty otherwise, but I feel that would likely be counter intuitive.

I would recommend you to read [this article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) about form helpers.

Comment: A dropdown could also be a valid solution!

Comment: yea I guessed it would be ok to just leave the answer rather than delete it.

Comment: I found that It was not saving the data.. but solution provided by @max worked fine.. Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to do either radio buttons or select tag,
From the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease), here's how to do the select tag, the radio buttons answer was provided by @Erick

```
f.select(:gender, [['Male', 'm'], ['Female', 'f']])
```

Comment: Thanks! gone through the link and found many things that, I was searching for.